# Python FTP problemas en descarga fichero de texto: codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

Estoy usando Pyton 3.8 y el módulo ftplib.
Pruebo contra el servidor libre [DLP](https://dlptest.com/):

```
with ftplib.FTP(host='ftp.dlptest.com',
                user='dlpuser',
                passwd='rNrKYTX9g7z3RgJRmxWuGHbeu') as ftp:
```

Todo funciona. Creo un directorio, subo un fichero de texto:

```
with open('C:/directorio/fichero.txt', 'rb') as txt_file:
    ftp.storlines('STOR fichero.txt', txt_file)
```

Pero cuando pretendo descargarlo con:

```
with open('C:/directorio/fichero2.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    def append_newline(line):
        txt_file.write(line + '\n')
    res = ftp.retrlines('RETR fichero.txt', append_newline)
```

Me dice que (resumo):

*return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8d' in position 4: character maps to undefined*

Recordar que hasta la versión Python3.11 debemos emplear la función callback para cada línea recibida, pues en los ficheros de texto se pierde el carácter de salto de línea ‘\n’ en la llamada a retrlines().

El fichero es un texto simple codificado en utf-8.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Abrelo en modo binario también para escribir, es decir, con `"wb"`.

Comment: No solo abrir en modo binario, si no también cambiar la función, queda así:    `with open('C:/directorio/fichero.txt', 'wb') as txt_file:
        res = ftp.retrbinary('RETR fichero2.txt', txt_file.write)`
Gracias @abulafia

Comment: Ahora pregunto: ¿Cual es la razón de no poder utilizar retrlines()?

Comment: Eso requiere una respuesta extensa. Hecho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando transfieres ficheros por FTP la opción más segura es transferirlos siempre en modo binario. Así te aseguras de que la transferencia realmente envía el fichero "tal cual" (no le añade retornos de carro que no estaban en el original) y lo recibirá también "tal cual".

Este consejo es obvio para ficheros que no sean de texto (imágenes, pdfs, archivos comprimidos con zip) pues en ese tipo de archivos añadir o quitar bytes los dejaría inservibles.

Pero incluso si lo que estás transfiriendo son ficheros de texto, resulta conveniente transferirlos en modo binario. Además del problema con los retornos de carro (que el propio protocolo FTP meterá o quitará si no está activado el modo binary en la transferencia), tienes el problema adicional del encoding (del cual el protocolo FTP no sabe nada, pero Python sí, a la hora del acceso a los ficheros locales).

Conviene tener claro entonces qué ocurre realmente durante una lectura de un fichero y su envío al servidor:

1. El fichero contiene bytes, en un cierto encoding (tú dices que es utf8 en tu caso)
2. Cuando lo abres en modo binario con la opción `"rb"` de `open()`,  la posterior lectura del fichero producirá los bytes tal cual estuvieran en el fichero, sin que el encoding importe. Si lo hubieras abierto en modo texto (opción `"w"`), Python habría intentado decodificar esos bytes para convertirlos a caracteres, y entonces el encoding sería fundamental porque si no es el correcto se producirán errores en la codificación. Por otro lado `ftp.storlines()` espera que el fichero esté abierto en modo binario.
3. Los datos que se envían al servidor son bytes, y el servidor los almacena sin cambiarlos y sin necesidad de conocer el encoding. Pero puede añadir retornos de carro adicionales a cada línea si has usado `.storlines()` (cosa que no ocurre si usas `.storbinary()`

Y cuando luego intentas recuperar el mismo fichero:

1. Abres el fichero en modo `"w"`, por lo que está abierto en modo texto y presupone un encoding (será utf8 por defecto)
2. Usas `.retrlines()` para recibir los contenidos del servidor. Esa función elimina los retornos de carro que vengan (lo que ya puede ser un inconveniente) y **además** intenta decodificar los bytes que llegan para convertirlos en texto. Para eso necesita conocer la codificación de esos bytes (y realmente ftplib no la sabe, sólo la sabes tú como programador). ftplib usa una codificación por defecto, pero si no era esa, habrá problemas.
3. Los bytes que han llegado, una vez convertidos a texto por ftplines, se vuelcan al fichero con `.write()` donde les añades el retorno de carro que se les había quitado. Pero ese retorno de carro (local) puede no coincidir con el remoto. En definitiva estás guardando otra versión del fichero que puede ser idéntica o no al original. Además, `.write()` necesita codificar de nuevo a bytes el texto recibido, para lo que usará un *encoding* (por defecto uft8) que puede coincidir o no con el que tenía el archivo recibido desde el servidor.

Para garantizar que sean idénticos, lo mejor es transferirlos en modo binario como dije antes, así:

```
import ftplib
with ftplib.FTP(host='ftp.dlptest.com',
                user='dlpuser',
                passwd='rNrKYTX9g7z3RgJRmxWuGHbeu') as ftp:
  with open('fichero.txt', 'rb') as txt_file:
      ftp.storbinary('STOR fichero.txt', txt_file)                
  with open('fichero2.txt', 'wb') as txt_file:
      def append_block(block):
          txt_file.write(block)
      res = ftp.retrbinary('RETR fichero.txt', append_block)
```

Esto garantiza que lo que subes al servidor es una copia *idéntica* de lo que tenías en disco, y que lo que luego bajas del servidor es una copia *idéntica* de lo que el servidor tiene almacenado. Es decir, al final "fichero.txt" y "fichero2.txt" son idénticos byte a byte.

Si insistes en hacerlo mediante `.storlines()` y `.retrlines()`, entonces debes conocer el encoding del fichero, asegurarte de asignar el valor correcto a `ftp.encoding` para la transferencia, y usar el mismo encoding para escribir el fichero que recibas. Así:

```
import ftplib
with ftplib.FTP(host='ftp.dlptest.com',
                user='dlpuser',
                passwd='rNrKYTX9g7z3RgJRmxWuGHbeu') as ftp:
  ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
  with open('fichero.txt', 'rb') as txt_file:
      ftp.storlines('STOR fichero.txt', txt_file)                
  with open('fichero2.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as txt_file:
      def append_line(line):
          txt_file.write(line + "\n")
      res = ftp.retrlines('RETR fichero.txt', append_line)
```

Ahora bien, este código puede fallar si el archivo que intentas enviar no está realmente codificado con utf8.

Comment: Por abundar: En la versión 3.9 (copiopego) _Se agregó el parámetro encoding, y el valor predeterminado se cambió de Latin-1 a UTF-8 para seguir RFC 2640_. Como estoy con la 3.8, se liaba más la madeja. La conclusión, como apuntas @abulafia, todo en binario.